# Why will this query not insert data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Using the follow code I am unable to insert data.

```
try:
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    sql='insert into `quanList` (`Title`) values(%s)'
    cursor.execute(sql,(getQuan.Title))
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It may help to provide the full error you are receiving, so that we can properly help get you an answer.